# NHibernate QueryOver equivalent of HQL With?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, queryover

What is the QueryOver API equivalent of a [WITH](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/05/17/nhibernate-2-1-0-hql-with-clause.aspx) clause in HQL?  I have not been able to find one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the same naming in the example you link to:

```
Animal m = null;
Animal a = null;
var query = session.QueryOver<Animal>(() => a)
          .Inner.JoinAlias(()=> a.mother, ()=> m, ()=> m.bodyWeight < someLimit);
```

Comment: This appears to be a version 3.2 feature.  Bummer.  Now I need to see about upgrading.  Thanks for the info!!